# Using ReactJs, How do I update my form fields when my parent object sent in from props changes?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, reactjs.net

I am using REactJs to dynamically create some form fields. these form fields are mapped to a document object. Visually it is a three column app. A document queue displayed on left with many clickable document icons , fields in the middle and the document image on the right. There can be multiple documents. Each document has fields associated to it. If a user inputs values into the fields then clicks another document. I want the input fields to be reset for the new document or saved values loaded.

Below is the last attempt i tried where I am using the DefaultValue attribute; i've tried to pass the values in from a function. I ve also tried value attribute but that locks the value not allowing the user to change it.

Currently I successfully save the state of the document queue and its fields but i just cannot get the UI to reflect my state object: documentQueue.

I ve read where people suggest using value={state} but that doesn't quite work for my state object. My forms are more dynamic and complex.

```
var Fields = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return {                        
        currentDocumentIndex: 0,
        shouldUpdate: false,
        randomKey : 0
    };
},
componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps) {        
    console.log("compare props");
    console.log(nextProps.fields === this.props.fields);
    var forceRender = !(nextProps.fields === this.props.fields);
    //only change state if needed.
    if (forceRender) {
        if (!this.state.shouldUpdate) {
            this.setState({ shouldUpdate: true ,randomKey : Math.random() }, function () {
                console.log("should update fields state set");
                console.log(this.state.shouldUpdate);
            });
        }
    } else {
        if (this.state.shouldUpdate) {
            this.setState({ shouldUpdate: false , randomKey: Math.random() }, function () {
                console.log("should update fields state set");
                console.log(this.state.shouldUpdate);
            });
        }
    }
},
getDataType: function (datatype, fieldId) {        
    switch (datatype) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            return <div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" key={this.state.randomKey+1} className="form-control" id={fieldId} onChange={this.onValueChanged.bind(this)} value={this.props.fields[fieldId]}  /></div>
        case 5:
            return <div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" key={this.state.randomKey+2} className="form-control" id={fieldId}  onChange={this.onValueChanged.bind(this)}  /></div>
        case 6:
            return <div class="col-sm-6"><input type="checkbox" key={this.state.randomKey+3} className="form-control" id={fieldId} value="true" onChange={this.onChecked.bind(this)} /></div>
        case 7:
            return <div class="col-sm-6"><textarea type="text" rows="5" key={this.state.randomKey+4} className="form-control" id={fieldId} onChange={this.onValueChanged.bind(this)}  ></textarea></div>
    }
},    
onChecked : function(event){        
},
onValueChanged : function(event){   
    this.props.onFieldChange(this.props.currentDocumentIndex, event.target.id, event.target.value);                
},
renderFields: function () {
    var fieldNames = [];        
    if (this.props.doctype == null) {
        console.log("fields are null");            
    } else {
        console.log("fields are valid from Field component");            
        for (var index = 0; index < this.props.doctype.Fields.length; index++)
        {                
            var inputField = this.getDataType(this.props.doctype.Fields[index].DataType, this.props.doctype.Fields[index].DocumentTypeFieldID);                
            fieldNames.push(<label className="control-label col-sm-6">{this.props.doctype.Fields[index].Name}</label>);                
            fieldNames.push(inputField);
        }
    }               
    return (            
            <form className="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div className="form-group">
                    {fieldNames}
                </div>
            </form>            
    );        
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderFields()}
        </div>
        );             
}
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to manage an `input` value with React, you can use the `value` prop.

However, as you've seen, the user can no longer directly edit the field.

To allow user edits, you must also set `onChange` on the field and write the incoming edits somewhere such as `state`.

The [docs for `ReactLink`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html#reactlink-before-and-after) have a good example of this:

```
var NoLink = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {message: 'Hello!'};
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({message: event.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    var message = this.state.message;
    return <input type="text" value={message} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
});
```

Also, you may just want to use `ReactLink`.

Comment: I am using Reactjs.net I don't know how to add external components just yet.

Comment: onChange works where onBlur doesn't allowing me to change the value attribute. I now just need to figure out how to get this to work. Your simple example works fine but when i try the following, the value does not update                                                                                       value={this.getFieldValueFrom(this.props.currentDocumentIndex,fieldId)}

Comment: A quick once-over does not yield anything architecturally wrong with your code. I'd try a `debugger` statement in both `getFieldValueFrom` and `setFieldValueFrom` and see where you end up.

Comment: This answer as well as the this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/8JgClU9jol0                            helped me resolve the issue. I wanted to beable to reset the fields when a parent props changed. I used a key value on the input elements to make this happen. I also used componentWillReceiveProps to know when the props changed. I then created a state variable that would update my key value for the input elements when the parent prop changed.